# Use parameter expansion to modify output of another expansion

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use the Bash parameter expansions to modify the output of a command substitution or another parameter expansion.

The following nested expansions work quite well in Zsh; but result in a "bad substitution" error in Bash:

```
${${PWD##*/}//trunk/latest}
```

or

```
${$(basename $PWD)//trunk/latest}
```

the output should be the last folder of the `$PWD`, replaced by `latest` when my current directory is `trunk`

so `/home/user/trunk` should become `latest`

Is there a Bash equivalent allowing to chain expansions without relying on variables or pipes? Or do Bash expansions only allows the input to be a string or a plain variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that nesting of substitution operators is unique to `zsh`.

Note that with `zsh` like with `(t)csh`, you can also do `${PWD:t:s/trunk/latest/}`.

Though `bash` also supports those csh history modifiers for history expansion, it doesn't support them for its parameter expansions.

Here with `bash`, use a temporary variable:

```
var=${PWD##*/} var=${var//trunk/latest}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this with bash:

```
[[ $PWD =~ .*/(.*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]//trunk/latest}"
```

---

or with one command:

```
[[ $PWD =~ .*/(.*) && ${BASH_REMATCH[1]//trunk/latest} =~ (.*) ]]
```

The result is in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`

Answer (score 0):

do you want...?

```
PWD=latest
```

I don't see a method to your request. If you want to replace all of `$PWD` w/ latest - though the best way to do that is to `cd` to latest.

```
[ /home/user/trunk = "$PWD" ] && OLDPWD=../latest cd -
```

...which will take you to latest and print the pathname to stdout. You can get right back where you came from by doing `cd -` again. You can do the same w/ `$CDPATH`:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/{1..5}  ; \
CDPATH=/tmp cd 3; cd -; \
echo "${CDPATH:-empty or unset::}" "$OLDPWD"
```

---

```
/tmp/3
/home/mikeserv
empty or unset:: /tmp/3
```

Comment: The issue does not lay in the substitution itself, it can be achieve with `sed` in few steps. But i don't understand why bash refuse to execute subshell, then replace its content like any other string